# Enforce class constraints in type class that is not captured in the type signature of implementing type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use a typeclass that enforces a constraint on the type returned by  one of the functions it defines. But the return type of the function does not capture the constraint in its type variable. I would like to know what is wrong with the code or what is the correct way to encode it. 
A sample code is given below:

```
  data State a = State {
    uniform :: a
  }
  class Renderable a where
    render :: (Uniform b) => Int -> a -> State b

  library :: (Uniform a) => a -> IO ()
  -- some implementation

  draw :: (Renderable a) => a -> IO ()
  draw renderable = do
    let state = render 0 renderable
    _ <- library (uniform state)
```

In the above snippet, the `render` function tries to enforce that the `uniform` property in State adheres to a class constraint Uniform. When I run the code, I am getting an error that

```
 Could not deduce (Uniform a5) arising from a use of ‘draw’
  from the context: (Renderable r, Uniform a)
  bound by the type signature for:
               draw :: forall r a.
                       (Renderable r, Uniform a) =>
                       Int -> Renderable r -> IO ()
```

Thinking of it, I am sort of able to understand that since the type of `draw` uses only `Renderable` and `Renderable` does not have a parameter of type `Uniform` in its type signature, the compiler is not able to verify the flow completely. But I am wondering, why cant the compiler, while testing the type signature of `draw` ignore the issue and basically depend on the fact that it will know if a type implementing `Renderable` will definitely have to provide a value for `uniform` as a part of `State` and it can verify the type correctness in the implementation site rather than usage.

PS: This is an extracted snippet from OpenGL code and `Uniform`, `Library` are opengl terminologies.

Comment: This is a very common mistake.  The signature you have given `(Uniform b) => Int -> a -> State b` means that it must work for *all* `b`.  So if some caller requests a `State Elephant`, the function must know how to return that.  I think the correct design here is to return a monomorphic (no type variables) data type from `render` -- though it's hard to advise since I can't really tell what you intend to do with the result of render.

Comment: @luqui I get the issue you said. But as I said, the compiler can still verify whether the `Elephant` adheres to `Uniform` in the implementation place where an Elephant is returned isnt it? To your second question, as I had given in the example, my intention is to pass the type adhering to Ùniform` to a function  : `library :: (Uniform a) => a -> IO ()`

Comment: It looks to me like you just need to specify what type the result of that call to `uniform` is supposed to be. Currently both the producer and consumer of that value are polymorphic, so the  compiler doesn't know what instance to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a technique for you.  I've [written about this](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) many years ago (in a slightly different context, but the idea is the same) and I still stand by it.

First, the framing.  If we write out the signature of `render` explicitly, we have:

```
render :: forall b. Uniform b => Int -> a -> State b
```

That is, the *caller* of render chooses the type `b`.  It seems to me that your intention is more like this pseudo-Haskell*:

```
render :: exists b. (Uniform b) & Int -> a -> State b
```

In which the *callee* gets to choose the type.  That is, different implementations of `render` may choose different types `b` to return, so long as they are uniform.

This might be a fine way to phrase it, except that Haskell does not support existential quantification directly.  You can make a wrapper data type to simulate it

```
data SomeUniform where
    SomeUniform :: Uniform a => a -> SomeUniform
```

making your signature

```
render :: Int -> a -> SomeUniform
```

which I think has the properties you are looking for.  *However* the `SomeUniform` type and the `Uniform` typeclass are very likely superfluous.  You said in the comments that the `Uniform` typeclass looks like this:

```
class Uniform a where
    library :: a -> IO ()
```

Let's consider this question: let's say we have a `SomeUniform`, that is, we have a value of some type `a` about which we know nothing except that it is an instance of the `Uniform` typeclass.  What can we possibly do with `x`?  There is only one way to get any information out of `x`, and that is to call `library` on it.  So in essence the only thing the `SomeUniform` type is doing is carrying around a `library` method to be called later.  This whole *existential/typeclass* is kind of pointless, we would be better served collapsing it down to a simple *data type*:

```
data Uniform = Uniform { library :: IO () }
```

and your `render` method becomes:

```
render :: Int -> a -> Uniform
```

It's so beautifully unfancy, isn't it?  If there were more methods in `Uniform` typeclass, they would become additional fields of this data type (whose types may be functions, which can take some getting used to).  Where you had types and instances of the typeclass, e.g.

```
data Thingy = Thingy String
-- note the constructor type Thingy :: String -> Thingy

instance Uniform String where
    library (Thingy s) = putStrLn $ "thingy " ++ s
```

you can now also be rid of the data type and just use a function in place of the constructor

```
thingy :: String -> Uniform
thingy s = Uniform { library = putStrLn $ "thingy " ++ s }
```

(If you can't get rid of the data type for other reasons, you can provide a conversion function instead `uniformThingy :: Thingy -> Uniform`)

The principle here is, you may replace an existential type with the collection of its observations, and it's usually pretty nice if you do.

---

*** My pseudo-Haskell `&` is dual to `=>`, playing essentially the same role but for existentially quantified dictionaries.  `c => t` means that once the *caller* provides the dictionary `c`, the type `t` is returned, whereas `c & t` means that the *callee* provides both the dictionary `c` *and* the type `t`.

Comment: From what OP said, I get the impression that `Uniform`, `library`, etc are imported from an existing OpenGL module, so I doubt he can just change them like this. That said, I think it's an excellent approach in general. I actually read your blog post a few months back, and it's really impacted my approach to designing interfaces like this, so cheers ^^

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that.  In that case `SomeUniform` is a decent middle ground.

Comment: Thanks @Luqui for the explanation. Making the typeclasses into Data types seems to be an interesting approach. It seems more flexible for me

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're expecting to be able to define `render` to return a different distinct type for each implementation of `Renderable`, as long as that type is `Uniform`:

```
instance Renderable Foo where
  render _ _ = State True

instance Renderable Bar where
  render _ _ = State "mothman"

instance Renderable Baz where
  render _ _ = State 19
```

So if `render` is called with a `Foo`, it will return a `State Bool`, but if it's called with a `Bar` it will return a `State String` (assuming both `Bool` and `String` are `Uniform`). This is not how it works, and you'll get a type mismatch error if you try instantiating like this.

`render :: (Uniform b) => Int -> a -> State b` means that a `Uniform b => State b` is returned. If this is what your type signature is, your implementation must be no more or less specific; your implementation must be able to return a value of ANY type `Uniform b => State b`. If it is not able to do so, any code that requests a return value of a specific type won't get the right type, and things will break in ways that the type system SHOULD be able to prevent.

Let's look at a different example:

```
class Collection t where
  size :: Num i => t a -> i
```

Assume someone wants to run this `size` function, and get the result as a `Double`. They can do that, because any implementation of `size` must be able to return any type of class `Num`, so the caller can always specify which type they want. If you were allowed to write an implementation that always returned an `Integer`, this would no longer be possible.

---

I think to do what you're trying to do, you'd need something like [`FunctionalDependencies`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies). With this, your class can be something like:

```
class Uniform b => Renderable a b | a -> b where
  render :: Int -> a -> State b
```

The "`| a -> b`" tells the type checker that the type `b` should be decided based on the type `a` provided by the caller. This disallows the caller from choosing their own `b`, which means the implementation should force a more specific type. Note that now you need to specify both `a` and `b` in your instances, so:

```
instance Renderable Foo Bool where ...
instance Renderable Bar String where ...
```

I'm certain there are other valid approaches to this problem, as well.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. While I understand your answer, Is it correct for to think "caller can always specify which type they want"? The guarantee that the typeclass provides is that the result will adhere to a constraint `Uniform`. Thats all. So In the `Collection` example, isnt it still totally fine that an implementation always returns Integer? Because it still adheres to a Num. I am not able to understand the complete reasoning behind your explanation. Maybe I am missing something. Can you explain more?

Comment: @AravindhS yeah you're not correct.  That's just the meaning of a type variable in a signature, the *caller* chooses.  When I call `read :: (Read a) => String -> a`, *I* decide what type is being read -- I can read a `String` or a `[Int]` or whatever, and `read` must be prepared to transform a string into that type.  So when you are implementing `render`, you must be prepared to provide *any* type that is requested of you, as long as the requested type satisfies the constraint.  It feels very different than OO languages, I know.

Comment: @AravindhS It's the caller's job to choose types within the constraints of the type signature, so the callee needs to be able to handle all types that might fit the signature. The type checker doesn't really distinguish between "parameter types" and "return types", it treats them the same. It's no more fine for a `Collection` instance to always return an `Integer` than it is for `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b` to only accept an `Int64`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now. I think TypeFamilies also can be used to express this relation. Is this correct?

Comment: @AravindhS I think that's a different thing. TypeFamilies allows you to define a special sort of parametric type synonym that resolves to completely different types depending on its type parameter. So if you define a type family `Foo a`, you can instantiate `Foo Char` to be a type synonym for `String`, and `Foo Bool` to mean `Int`, whatever you want. This is especially useful when you define a type family inside of a class, then each instance of the class can instantiate that family with its own special type.